# Unity GameObject.BroadcastMessage() not work on IOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I am using `GameObject.BroadcastMessage()` to call specific function which is "ResetPuzzleElement". It is working for Android(I have tried myself), but when export to IOS platform, It does not work, I have no idea how to troubleshoot this and I can't find on google any other people having the same issue.

Unity Version : 2017.2.0f3

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @MGDroid I am using UnityEvent. I will attach screenshot.

Comment: Don't use `GameObject.BroadcastMessage` in Unity. Implement your own event system or find better ones online. I've seen reports of `GameObject.BroadcastMessage` not working before but usually, Unity can't fix it if you file for a bug report because they can't replicate it. Also, `GameObject.BroadcastMessage` is slow.....